# how to locate webelement with innertext

Tags: c#, selenium, element, getelementsbytagname, qwebelement

I use **selenium** with **C#** to write a test, but now I face a problem.

Here is my html. How can I  locate the "100" on the web page?

```
< ul>

 < li class=""> 100 < /li>

 < li class=""> 200 < /li>

 < li class=""> 300 < /li>

 < li class=""> 400 < /li>

 < li class=""> 500 < /li>

< /ul>
```

Answer (score 8):

```
IWebDriver Driver = new FirefoxDriver();
IWebElement element = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//li[text()=' 100 ']"));
```

Comment: When there are spaces at the beginning or the end of a text I prefer to use contains() function. So the xpath would be "//li[contains(text(), '100')]"

Comment: Yes, that's very true, but I got the impression it was just a typo in his sample code. There are many ways to find elements, he should chose the one that works well for him.

Answer (score 4):

It can be also done without xpath:

```
driver.FindElements(By.TagName("li")).Where(elem => elem.Text.Trim() == "100").FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I am not sure if it is the fastest way to do this. As it goes for each element in the DOM to check if it is equal to that thing or not. Whereas, XPath just goes once and does the comparison in a single call.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to do it this way:

1. Get all the elements on the page.
2. Iterate through the elements checking the text.

```
IList<IWebElement> allElements = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("*"));
foreach (var element in allElements)
{
    if (element.Text == "My inner text that I am looking for") { element.Click(); }
}
```